# chart widget using SVG rendering

Tags: jquery, javascript, jquery-svg

I was looking for a javascript chart generating widget, that uses SVG rendering.
I found something like www.jqwidgets.com but the licensed version is not free.
I found another one called yui charts with BSD licence which i can use commercially, but this one is using flash.

Does anyone know any chart widget that uses SVG rendering and is free for commercial use?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the wonderful [gRaphaël](http://g.raphaeljs.com/) library, a subproject of Raphaël, does exactly what you need.

It's MIT licensed, uses javascript and SVG, and the parent library isn't just for graphs but for anything with vector graphics - with the advantage over canvas approaches that it receives DOM events.

It doesn't depend / integrate with jQuery, but this isn't actually needed in practice.

Comment: it looks quite neat, but doesn't looks quite easy to use it or may b its just me

Comment: Check the source code of the demos to get started quick, but simple charts are usually a matter of calling functions like barchart(x, y, width, height, [1,2,3]) over your raphael object.

Answer (score 0):

d3.js is not exactly a widget, but rather a rich data visualization library, with the option to output to SVG. What kind of "charts" exactly do you want to generate?

Comment: d3.js? i currently want line charts and bar charts, also having pie chart would be nice

Comment: Well, you can do all those things with d3.js, and very elegantly, although it might not be quite as out-of-the-box as you would like. You could look at Highcharts, which appears to be more oriented to business graphics, although I haven't tried it myself.